# What's the Manhwa where the protagonist is a demon king in the future?

Tags: story-identification, manga

I vaguely remember the logo for the manhwa being a skull on fire in a phone.

And the main plot is that the MC was going to become the demon lord, then a female knight who came from the future was supposed to kill him, but saved him instead. And some story plot happens and she died protecting him, and now he is just going around waiting for her to be born so they can be reunited.

The first chapter starts off with a girl using an app that transported her into another world where she can "level up" so to speak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Warble](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=152360)

Although the plot you remember happens is revealed much later(at last few chapter).

Jude Park is Grimore King in the future(evil side). The female knight (Warlock) do come back and create an app to help mankind become stronger for fighting evil. She want to kill him because he is kinda invincible in her past life and almost eradicate human. She change her mind and train him but end up die in Baal hand in order to save him.

This is the cover hope it help you remind it
[image: Warble]

Comment: Oh nice thanks, I was wondering about it, cause I remember the author when on a break and I wanted to check back on it.